# Generating appropriate number of reducer outputs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, output

I am running a simple map and reduce `Hadoop` job. The property `mapred.reduce.tasks` has been set by `Hadoop` administrator in `mapred-site.xml` file. Say it is 25. Now, my job produces only 4 different keys, so only 4 out of 25 `part-r-xxxx` files are non-empty, rest are empty files. How do I prevent this? I only want as many number of output files as number of keys produced (which I do not know upfront).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using the `LazyOutputFormat`:

```
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
```

This will ensure that your output files are created only if there is some actual data for that reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also override FileOutputCommitter's needsTaskCommit() function.

Check this [blog by Chris](http://whiteycode.blogspot.in/2012/06/hadoop-removing-empty-output-files.html) to achieve that.